# How to get an element's current CSS value

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can you get current border value? Is dashed or dotted or other?

```
eg.

    .block { width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#abc;border:dashed 1px #000000;}

<div class="block"></div>
```

eg.
Click A button change the border value to 3px but keep dashed & color.

then click B button change the border dashed to dotted but keep it 3px & color.

Comment: For what element, under what circumstances, in response to what event..?

Answer (score 2):

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not
>   supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin,
>   use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so
>   on.

You'll have to pick a specific border like `'border-top-style'` to get `dashed`, `dotted` etc. (which should be the same as whatever you applied with the `border` shorthand)

```
$(".block").css('border-top-style')
```

---

eg. Click A button change the border value to 3px but keep dashed & color.

```
$(".block").css({'border-top-width': '3px', 'border-right-width': '3px', 'border-bottom-width': '3px', 'border-left-width': '3px'})
```

then click B button change the border dashed to dotted but keep it 3px & color.

```
$(".block").css({'border-top-style': 'dotted', 'border-right-style': 'dotted', 'border-bottom-style': 'dotted', 'border-left-style': 'dotted'})
```

Comment: Well,that mean it has border-middle-style & border-bottom-style ??

Comment: Oh! thank you, I know that is the Shorthand CSS properties problem!

Comment: Yeah border is shorthand. Actually macek points out you can use `border-width`  and `border-style` instead of doing the individual Top right bottom left! Didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Some Html

```
<p>Hello</p>
<button id="a">A</button>
<button id="b">B</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Some jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $("#a").click(function(){
        $("p").css('border', '3px solid red');
    });
    $("#b").click(function(){
        $("p").css('border-style', 'dashed');
    });
    $("#reset").click(function(){
        $("p").css('border','none');
    });

});
```

See it work on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAnGq/)